# c++ std::weak_ptr to stack object

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I need a pointer to a stack object that might go out of scope. I have been told that a weak pointer can achieve this, but the following code throws a seg fault:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
int main()
{

    std::weak_ptr<int> wp;

    {
        auto a = 4;

        wp = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, [](auto){});
        assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4);
    }

    assert(wp.lock().get() == nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this?

*edit*

I have found a solution that seems to work.

```
std::weak_ptr<int> wp;

{
    auto a = 4;

    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, [](auto){});
    wp = sp;
    assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4);
}

assert(wp.lock().get() == nullptr);
```

But a commenter has told me this is undefined behavior. Why does this work, and why is it UB?

*edit2*

Another commenter has said that it is because the shared pointer stays in scope, but if that is the case, why does this still work?

```
std::weak_ptr<int> wp;

{
    auto a = 4;
    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<int>();

    {
        sp = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, [](auto){});
        wp = sp;
        assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4);
    } //shared pointer out of scope

    assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4);

} // stack object out of scope

assert(wp.lock().get() == nullptr);
```

Comment: The `shared_ptr` does the work of tracking the lifetime of the variable it points to. It does this by assuming it's own lifetime is the same. But in the first example, the `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed immediately.

Comment: Be careful with this solution. It's usually assumed that `std::shared_ptr` are very safe to copy and pass around. That's their main strength. It would be easy for someone to try to use the `shared_ptr` in a way that would break what you are trying to do. In fact, it seems hard to imagine a function that *needs* a `shared_ptr` that wouldn't also try to move or copy it, which would break this approach. Edit : This solution looks to me like it is trying to work around critically poor design decisions.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe: problem your code suppose to solve, not how to fix your solution of the problem.

Comment: In the 3rd example, the shared_ptr goes out of scope after the **2nd** assert, not after the **1st** assert as the comment in code says. That is why the code still works. The lifetime of the shared_ptr is defined by the `sp` variable it is assigned to, not by the block where the `shared_ptr()` constructor is called.

Comment: For the 2nd edit, what matters is that the longest lived copy of the shared_ptr doesn't outlive the stack object it points to.

Comment: _"I need a pointer to a stack object that might go out of scope."_  Make the object held by a shared_ptr to begin with, rather than trying to wrap shared_ptr and weak_ptr around a stack based object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines of code:

```
wp = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, [](auto){});
assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4);
```

Here you create a `std::shared_ptr`, initialize `wp` from it and immediately destroy the `std::shared_ptr`. At the point of `assert` `wp` is already expired and `lock()` returns a null `std::shared_ptr`. Dereferencing a null pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Other than the above, the general approach is workable:

```
{
    auto a = 4;

    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, [](auto){}); // create a shared_ptr and keep it
    wp = sp; // initialize weak_ptr from it
    assert(*wp.lock().get() == 4); // sp is still alive, so wp.lock().get() != nullptr
}
```